# using simple_form with bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone know how to change the class simple_form uses from 'controls' to 'form-control'. This was a change made in Bootstrap 3. I know there are many options in config/initializers/simple_form.rb and config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb but I can't find what I need.

```
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, :tag => 'div', :class => 'control-group', :error_    class => 'error' do |b|
   b.use :html5
   b.use :placeholder
   b.use :label
   b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
     ba.use :input
     ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
    ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

in the above you can swap out 'control-group' for 'form-group', but I see no way to change the class for the input tag.

Comment: Did you tried `ba.use :input, :wrap_with => { :class => 'form-control' }` ?

Comment: yes, that applies the given class to a div that wraps the <input> element

Comment: `config.input_class = 'form-control'` default class for inputs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In newer simple_form versions, there is a new global config you can use:

```
config.input_class = "form-control"
```

You need the gem version >3.0.0 which depends on rails >4.0.0, or the upcoming 2.2 release. You can use the v2.2 branch on github for now.

See https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/v2.2/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I didn't see that because I'm not running the latest beta of simpleform. Now I have to update to rails 4 and update simpleform and move to bootstrap 3. haha

Comment: any ideas about how to fix the buggy checkbox inputs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571748/rails-4-form-builder-with-comprehensive-support-for-twitter-bootstrap-3 doesn't exist yet.

Comment: `config.input_class` is no longer supported.

Comment: I can confirm, this no longer seems to work. It didn't for me with Rails 4.2.0 and simple_form 3.1.0. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the default wrapper in your simple_form_bootstrap.rb initializer?

```
  config.wrappers :bootstrap, tag: :div, class: "form-group", error_class: "has-error" do |b|

    # Form extensions
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder

    # Form components
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: :div do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block text-danger" }
    end
  end
```

Comment: btw they are now using the class "form-group" instead as in the code above... they changed it since beta